# Entity Framework One-to-Zero or One, Optional Table Rows Always Created

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have done my due-diligence searching, but everything I have tried doesn't seem right. My scenario:

```
public class Stuff{
    public int StuffTypeA { get; set; }
    public int StuffTypeB { get; set; }

    public Creature Creature { get; set; }
}

public class Creature{
     public virtual Stuff MyStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Now, a creature can have stuff but not necessarily. Based on posts here and elsewhere, I have spent some time playing with fluid API and I can set up all kinds of relationships between the two.

The one the ends up looking the most like what I would expect is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Creature>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.MyStuff)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.Creature);
```

This creates nothing in the Creature table and a foreign key Creature_ID in the Stuff table - just what I would expect. However, every time I create a new creature a row is written to the Stuff table with default values. This is not what I want. Of my whole universe of Creatures, only a small fraction will actually have Stuff so all of these rows for nothing seem like a big waste. If I were designing the database, I would design it just like the above modelBuilder does, but EF doesn't use/interact with it as I would expect.

Am I not really doing the fluid api correctly? How do I say, "Only create the optional row when there is actually data to store there"?

Comment: What is the value of `MyStuff` on the instance of `Creature` when you add it to the database? It needs to be null if you don't want it to create a `Stuff` record, the fact that it is creating a record implies that it is a default instance of `Stuff`.

Comment: I wish I could mark this as answer. You are right. I was missing the forest for the trees...or something like that. Exactly as you indicate, I was in fact instantiating Stuff even though I didn't intend to. Once I stopped doing that, the rows stopped being created. Thanks!